# Using Studio's "Custom Tool" in MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, customtool

I've got a "Custom Tool" for Visual Studio to munge some template files into code. For consistency and portability I'd like to be able to run this template processor from MSBuild when building outside of Visual Studio.

Visual Studio creates the following snippets for the files:

```
<!-- the template -->
<None Include="Template.in">
  <Generator>Template Processor</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Template.in.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
<!-- generated file -->
<Compile Include="Template.in.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Template.in</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

The problem here is that the `Template.in` is only processed by the Studio, but not by MsBuild, which may lead to out-of-date `Designer.cs` files.

Is there a existing MSBuild task that can use the `IVsSingleFileGenerator` directly (including to load its location from the registry) or do I have to call the processor manually (either by implementing said MSBuild task myself or adapting the processor)?

Interestingly, the [Using MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166190.aspx) article on the MSDN says:

> Single file generators are accessible
>   at design-time only, but MSBuild tasks
>   can be used at design-time and
>   build-time. For maximum flexibility,
>   therefore, use MSBuild tasks to
>   transform and generate code. For more
>   information, see Project Items (Visual
>   Studio SDK).

---

**Update:** I've hacked this specific custom tool into a msbuild task, but it's not pretty. I'd still prefer a well maintained generic solution. I've [posted the source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100905141112/http://dasz.at/index.php/2010/02/building-a-simple-msbuild-task/) on my blog.

Comment: I went to a fair amount of trouble to write a SFG (see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686405/Writing-a-Single-File-Generator) only to realize at the end that they don't build automatically and don't work with MSBuild. What's a better approach? I can't access your blog link.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify your custom tool from within VisualStudio, what does it add to your project or solution files?  Since they are just msbuild files, you might be able to use the added xml as a template for your own build files.